# Connecting visitors in different browsers

Tags: adobe-analytics

We are tracking a forgot password workflow action using adobe site catalyst. The flow happens something like below

1. User requests for forgot password
2. He provides the email address and clicks on create new password
3. New password generation like is send to his email address
4. User clicks on this link and generates a new password

First 3 actions occurs in the same browser. The 4th activity can occur in the same browser or a different browser. Because of this, site catalyst considers that user as a different one (different visitor ID) and considers that as a totally different visit. Ideally the number of users who completes activity 4 should be less than that completes 1,2,3.
But for us, we are seeing more users who completes activity 4 which could be because of this different visitor issue.

Can someone please suggest a better approach to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try overwriting the Visitor ID.

I do not know how your site works in the backend, but generally, and theoretically (as I have yet to be asked by clients on to implement this):

1. Extract the Visitor ID when the user provides the email address and clicks on create new password. You might want to check the [appendVisitorIDsTo (Cross-Domain Tracking)](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/mcvid/mcvid-appendvisitorid.html) function out and see how the Visitor ID query parameter is implemented.
2. Send the Visitor ID along with the email address to your backend controller that spits out the template forget password email.
3. In the template forget password email, append the extracted Visitor ID as a query parameter in the reset link.
4. In DTM (if you are using DTM), modify your Marketing Cloud Visitor Service tool enable this configuration: [overwriteCrossDomainMCIDAndAID](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/mcvid/mcvid-overwrite-visitor-id.html).

When the user clicks on this reset link, the Visitor ID should be the one that is initially created for the user.

You might want to read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28611034/1199781) as well.